# Breach of confidentiality

Tags: confidentiality, pregnancy

If I’ve told my manager that my partner is pregnant and they tell other members of staff that she’s pregnant is it a breach of confidentiality or not

Comment: I imagine that much would depend on the context of your disclosure to your manager.   You may want to provide additional detail.

Comment: Such information is not about work I presume (?) it's personal so ...

Comment: But yeah, please provide more  info so we can help you better :)

Comment: You also need to provide a jurisdiction, and be clearer what you are asking. Are you asking in a strict legal sense, workplace policy sense, moral sense, what?

Comment: If your manager tells others, what are you going do? Sue them? Report them? I doubt that. If you want to keep this a secret, it's just easier not to tell them.

Comment: Jurisdiction, and the obvious question is whether you told your manager that this information is confidential.

Comment: Why did you tell them? What where you trying to achieve with this disclosure?

Comment: Was the manager even aware that this information was still secret? Did they disclose it in the same manner that you did? For example, if you told your manager, "I'm going to need time off in March because [partner] is pregnant", did they then tell co-workers, "Lewise may not be available for [project] because [partner] is pregnant", or did they mention it in passing, or something else?

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are a few things to check here.

- Could you reasonably *expect* privacy?

Did you *have* to tell your boss, because some law, regulation or company policy made you? Then the same source will very likely hold the key to your expectations. If you were required by law, I'm sure that law says what they are to do and what *not* to do with that information. If it was a company guideline, I'm sure they have a sentence or two how to handle that information. If it was just you two chatting, then maybe you explicitely told your boss about the expected level of privacy? If neither of those is true, then I'm afraid it comes down to culture and common sense. They may have different default expectations. That's why it's never good to rely on implicit assumptions.

- By not treating this information confedential, did they breach any laws?

Well, you did not say which juristiction you were in, so there is no way to say. But generelly speaking, all countries have laws that prevent people from using information they gained in the workplace outside of the workplace. Call it corruption or insider trading or whatever you want, but those laws are pretty universal as the concept of compartmentalizing and privacy is universal. If there were laws involved in your expectation of privacy, I'm pretty sure they say what is legal to do with this information. Even if legally protected, passing this information to other legitemately interested parties is covered by laws. For example, if you asked for paternity leave, contacting a HR representative would be the only reasonable thing to do for your boss. Passing that information on towards the people that handle those cases is surely covered by laws. On the other hand, passing it on as idle chit-chat or gossip to random colleagues around the water cooler is prohibited by laws in many places.

- By not treating this information confidential, did they go against company policy?

Well, since we don't know the company, this one is for you to research.

Next steps:

- Were you required by law to report this and the information was passed to people that have no legitimate business reason to have that information? Your chance is good that this is illegal in your country. Contact a local lawyer and inform yourself what you can do now.
- Were you required by company policy to report this and the information was passed to people that have no legitimate business reason to have that information? Read your policy and contact your union representative, data protection officer or HR (in that order, contact those first that work *for you*, not for the company).
- Did you explicitely require privacy from your boss and they gave the information to someone who had no legitimate business reason to have that information? You could again contact your union representative, data protection officer or HR (in that order, contact those first that work *for you*, not for the company). However, your boss being a lying scumbag might be acceptable in your company. If that is the case, then there is little you can do.
- If your boss gave the information to someone with a legitimate business reason (let's say a HR representative, to check that your paternity leave does not overlap with too many others and maybe hire temps to compensate) then there is *very* little you can do. That is basically their duty to do, whether you *wanted* privacy, or not. Whether you *decided* to tell them or a law or regulation forced you too, this is what was supposed to happen, right? They cannot sit on this information and just do nothing.

So then we are at the last option... your boss is gossiping information at the water cooler that you consider confidential, but nobody else does. That is tough. But there is little you can do. Tell them that you want it to be confidential if you did not do that already. If they *still* gossip it around, you gained an insight into your boss, but you have to figure out what to do with that. Definetely stop giving them any information, maybe firing them (aka finding a new job) is in order if you value your privacy highly enough to not work with a gossipping scumback that does not respect your wishes.

Comment: In the US, radiation workers (bascially anyone needing a radiation monitoring badge) are encouraged to inform management that they are pregnant so that they can be temporarily reassigned to other work that  does not have the possibility of radiation harm to the child. This is considered a confidential disclosure.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

General rule of thumb, for friends at least, is that you say nothing until the Lady says something.

However at work, it's a little different.

I would happily say that it's poor form in terms of general etiquette.

But I'm not sure it's severe enough to consider it a breach of Confidence.

Comment: What is "The Lady"? Is this code for something?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie It's a general point about pregnancies. Saying that you shouldn't say anything to anyone until the [person who is pregnant] makes it public.

Comment: @Kaz Doesn't seem relevant here.